# how to enable laptop mode tools in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, power-management, battery

I have a Lenovo z570 running ubuntu 12.10 with a battery life approximately 1hr 30 min. Please help me maximize the battery life of my lenovo

Answer (score 3):

'Laptop mode tools' has become obsolete. I suggest to check out the Ubuntu wiki on [Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks) and the [Jupiter applet](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/jupiter-applet-officially-switches-to.html).

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with laptop mode or Jupiter, the best tool is at www.linrunner.de called TLP and it has a PPA, this is the only one that works well minus any intervention. I used powertop to see a saving of 12W on battery as compared to previous 16W.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire up the Terminal and paste this command in:

> 1. sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
> 2. restart your laptop

After rebooted, it should start by itself if you are running on battery.  You might want to check out Hectic Geek's LMT page.  It is very comprehensive.  Good luck!

Source: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/lmt-battery-life-enhancer-ubuntu-linux/

Based on your model, if it has an nVidia discrete graphics card, you can use Bumblebee to disable it.  Here is the instruction page.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: Sorry this is only valid for Ubuntu 11.10 and older. 12.04 and earlier have laptop mode incorporated into the kernel.